# How should I declare an instance of an inner class of classes that implement the same interface

Tags: java, oop, interface, inner-classes

I have the following structure

```
public interface I{...}

public class A implements I{
  ....

  public static class Inside{
    ...
    //data from here are used in A. Therefore tight coupling.
  }
}

public class B implements I{
  ....

  public static class Inside{
    ...
    //data from here are used in B.  Therefore tight coupling.
  }
}
```

Note that the implementation of `A.Inside` is somewhat different from `B.Inside`. Then I have another class that accesses `Inside` as

```
public class AW extends X{
  ...
}

public class BW extends X{
  ...
}

public class X{
  ...
  public Obj doSomeWork(Inside inside){
    mInside = inside;
    ....//some work
  }
}


//UsageB is similar in it's implementation of the B stack
public class UsageA{
  A.AW inst = new AW();
  Inside in = A.Inside();
  inst.doSomeWork(in);
}
```

**question:** What should be the type of `mInside`? I don't want to have two `mInside` variables.

`AW` is tailored for `A` and `BW` is tailored for `B`

Comment: Well do the two Inside type implement a common interface at all?

Comment: How have you imported `Inside` class in X.java ? You can do it explicit using A.Inside or B.Inside

Comment: What is the role of the interface `I` in this example ?

Comment: @JonSkeet this my friend is truly a great question!!! I have one problem: each `Inside` has a different set of static constants. I will try it out (i.e. common interface for Inside) and attempt resolving them with `instanceof` and casting: which I don't know if will work. But thanks for the great question. BUT to make the point: I was hoping to have X be implementation agnostic.

Comment: Well how can it be implementation agnostic when the implementations have nothing in common? You do understand that as far as the compiler and JVM are concerned, your two `Inside` classes are completely unrelated, right? The fact that they're both called `Inside` is irrelevant.

Comment: @JonSkeet your "question" worked. Do you mind posting as response so I may mark this thread as accepted?

Comment: @learner: Done, I think :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your two `Inside` types are currently unrelated - there's no way for `X.doSomeWork()` to do refer to "it's this type or that type" when they're entirely different types. The fact that they're both nested classes called `Inside` doesn't make any difference.

If you extract the common behaviour (that `X` wants to call) into an interface and make both `Inside` classes implement that interface, *then* you can use that commonality. Basically do exactly what you'd do if they *weren't* nested classes and *didn't* have the same name, because `X` doesn't care about either of those aspects.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, It depends on your code. I mean, if your code in X.java is:

```
import tests.A.Inside;

public class X {
    public static void doSomeWork (Inside inside ){
    }
}
```

Then `Inside` is the class implemented in A.java, however you can do it a bit more explicit, using:

```
import tests.A;

public class X {
    public static void doSomeWork (A.Inside inside ){
    }
}
```

So the method parameters is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you need this solution,
but:

```
interface I{
IInside getInside();
}
interface IInside{
    Object doWork();
}

class X {
    private I state;
}
```

simpler, where A\B can delegate actual execution to inner class:

```
interface I{

    Object doWork();
}
```